# perlbrew switch path order not permanent on MacOS Big Sur 11.4

Tags: path, switch-statement, persistent, perlbrew, permanent

I'm writing a step-by-step instruction guide to installing perlbrew on a newly built (from ISO) MacOS Big Sur (11.4) VM running on VMware Fusion.

I have been able to successfully install perlbrew. Here is what perlbrew info looks like:

**perlbrew info**

Current perl:
Using system perl.
Shebang: #!/usr/bin/perl

perlbrew:
version: 0.92
ENV:
PERLBREW_ROOT: /Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew
PERLBREW_HOME: /Users/jblaty/.perlbrew
PERLBREW_PATH: /Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/bin
PERLBREW_MANPATH:

Great! Now, I'll do perlbrew **switch perl-5.32.1** and then another perlbrew info:

**perlbrew info**

Current perl:
Name: perl-5.32.1
Path: /Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.1/bin/perl
Config: -de -Dprefix=/Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.1 -Aeval:scriptdir=/Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.1/bin
Compiled at: Jun 23 2021 14:43:45

perlbrew:
version: 0.92
ENV:
PERLBREW_ROOT: /Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew
PERLBREW_HOME: /Users/jblaty/.perlbrew
PERLBREW_PATH: /Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.1/bin
PERLBREW_MANPATH: /Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.1/man

Super! So I'm now running the perlbrew version of Perl in the VM. Here is what the path looks like now that I've switched...

**print $PATH**

**/Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.1/bin**:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

AWESOME! So in the path, MacOS finds the *perlbrew version* before the system version of Perl. Everything looks great so far, but I expect that a **perlbrew switch** to be *persistent* to each new terminal session I start. Keep in mind that I'm using zsh, and my .zshenv looks like this:

**cat .zshenv**

source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc

However, here's where things break. If I close that terminal session and open a new one, and then do another **perlbrew info**, here's what I get:

**perlbrew info**

Current perl:
Name: perl-5.32.1
Path: /Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.1/bin/perl
Config: -de -Dprefix=/Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.1 -Aeval:scriptdir=/Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.1/bin
Compiled at: Jun 23 2021 14:43:45

perlbrew:
version: 0.92
ENV:
PERLBREW_ROOT: /Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew
PERLBREW_HOME: /Users/jblaty/.perlbrew
PERLBREW_PATH: /Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.1/bin
PERLBREW_MANPATH: /Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.1/man

...everything looks just fine, right? However, if I have another look at the path:

**print $PATH**

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:**/Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/jblaty/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.1/bin**

***WRONG!*** The perlbrew bin directories are appended to the ***end of the path***, not the beginning as it was before I closed the terminal session, earlier.

Can anyone guide me as to:

1. What did I do wrong? Did I miss something in the install?
2. How do I fix perlbrew so the perlbrew bin paths gets prepended to the system paths in subsequent new terminal sessions?

I'm going to be creating instructions for Linux as well, so fixing this might help me understand what I need to do there.

Answer (score 1):

Add the initialization script to `~/.zshrc`.

```
echo 'source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc' >> ~/.zshrc
```

The [zsh startup file order](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Files.html#Files) is:

1. `/etc/zshenv`
2. `~/.zshenv`
3. `/etc/zprofile` <- system `PATH` set here
4. `~/.zprofile`
5. `/etc/zshrc`
6. `~/.zshrc`
7. `/etc/zlogin`
8. `~/zlogin`